# Extern, headers, global variables

Tags: c, header, global-variables, extern

I'm making a game, the current structure of my program is like the following...

[image: prog structure]

The problem I'm having is that I have a function in `init_game.c` that initialises the players boards with the necessary data, once I have these initialised boards I need `the_game.c` to use these initialised boards (from `init_game.c`).

I'm confused on how I would get this to work with `extern`'s

**EDIT:** Clarification - I'm wondering how I can use the `extern` keyword with my programs structure to allow me to use the players **initialised** 2D `char` array (which gets initialised in the file `init_game.c` but is first defined in the `attributes.h` file) in the file `the_game.c`

Added a picture below for clarification to my problem...
[image]

Comment: Define these variables globally in `main` and include `attribute.h` in main.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, my game functions are in `the_game.c` so including `attributes.h` in `main` will serve no purpose. My question may not have been clear, I'm confused about how to use `extern` in the way I mentioned (using an initialised variable from one file, in another file).

Comment: You should add a file called `globals.c` (which would `#include attributes.h`) in which you put the actual definition and initialization of these global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `init_game.c`, declare global variables,

```
char player_board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
char enemy_board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
```

Any file that includes `attributes.h` will then have access to these arrays, provided that file doesn't declare another variable with the same name.

In your `main`, you need to make sure that you call the initializing function from `init_game.c` before you call any function from `the_game.c` that uses the global arrays.

Comment: Okay, so in `the_game.c` how would I access the arrays? Just like `player_board[i][j]`? I'm very confused about `extern`.

Comment: You access it the same way you access any array of the same type. `extern` simply informs the compiler that the array is defined in another compilation unit, in this case `init_game.c`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a clear indication that your program design is flawed. The correct solution is then to fix the program design, not to implement spaghetti coding with global variables.

The best way to use this is to use object-oriented design, by creating "classes" or "ADTs" or "code modules" (these things basically mean the same thing in C, as there is no class keyword). Each such class consists of a .h file and a .c file. Use the object-oriented concepts of keeping classes autonomous, only doing their specific task without caring about the rest of the world. Use private encapsulation and put everything that is to be regarded as public in the .h file.

- Game is a class in your project. Therefore, everything that is related to the game shall be in that class.
- Initializing the game is most definitely related to the game class, so that code should be merged with game.h. It doesn't make sense to have it in a file of its own.
- If either of those files contain items that don't belong to the game class, such items needs to be moved to files of their own.
- If the game class proves to be too complex, which it most likely will, you need to split up the various properties of the game into sub-classes. For example, one class for handling boards, one class for handling players and so on.
- If your program design is correct, there should not be any global variables anywhere. If you ever find yourself using the extern keyword, your program design is flawed. Please note that static file scope variables are perfectly fine to use (though consider thread-safety issues).

Comment: I see, I always find it difficult to split my programs up properly when I program in C